# How can Import a csv file into a Django project?

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv

I can't import a `csv` file into my Django project.

I have a code that is already working that basically takes a csv file and output spendings on different categories (using pandas). I'm learning Django right now and I'm trying to include that code into my project. But everytime I try to run in it says `'No module named StatementOCTRev'`.

I'm not sure if it's a directory thing or a `pandasXdjango` thing.

I tried different approaches but none of them work. That led to an ugly code. So I apologize. Anyway here is my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from .budget import Categorize, Spending
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import mysite.StatementOCTRev
from import_export import resources
#import
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects
    return render(request, 'mysite/home.html', {'posts':posts})

def post(request,post_id):

    ################################

    coffeelist = ["WING", "COSTA", "CAFFEINE", "PASSO", "LA FELICE", "GULLUOGLU", "CARIBOU", "ARK COFFEE"]
    restlist = ["TALABAT", "SOLO", "MELENZANE", "PIZZA", "HARDEES", "HARDEE'S", "MCDONALDS", "GULF ROYAL", "SARAY", "Carriage"]
    gaslist = ["KNPC", "OULA", "ALFA"]

    read = pd.read_csv('StatementOCTRev.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")  # Read CSV

    # create a new dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Reference", "Debit", "Credit", "Balance"])

    df['Date'] = read.iloc[:, 0]
    df['Reference'] = read.iloc[:, 1]
    df['Debit'] = read.iloc[:, 2]
    df['Credit'] = read.iloc[:, 3]
    df['Balance'] = read.iloc[:, 4]
    df['Category'] = 'Misc.'

    for name in df.Debit:
        if name < 0:
            df.loc[df.Debit == name, 'Debit'] = name * -1

    df.Reference = [str(x).replace(str(x), str(x).upper()) for x in df.Reference]
    df.Reference = [x.strip().replace('POS', '') for x in df.Reference]
    df.Reference = [x.strip().replace('UTAP', '') for x in df.Reference]
    df.Reference = [x.strip().replace('@', '') for x in df.Reference]
    df.Reference = [x.strip().replace('-', '') for x in df.Reference]
    df.Reference = [x.strip().replace('_', '') for x in df.Reference]


    # ------------------------ Coffee

    Categorize(coffeelist, "Coffee")
    SpentOnCoffee = Spending("Coffee")

    # ------------------------ Restaurant

    Categorize(restlist, "Restaurant")
    SpentOnRest = Spending("Restaurant")

    # ------------------------ Gas

    Categorize(gaslist, "Gas")
    SpentOnGas = Spending("Gas")

    Other = 1296 - SpentOnRest - SpentOnCoffee - SpentOnGas

    coffeecategorized = Categorize(coffeelist, "Coffee")
    coffeespending = Spending("Coffee")


    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'mysite/post.html', {'post':post})
```

Note: You can see, I'm not telling post function to return anything related to the file, that's because I actually couldn't go any further. Of course I want to. but I just want to make the code read the csv file first.

Also, `models.py` has nothing related to this `csv` file (it only has a Post class as app is just a blog that I'm making to exercise Django.)

Comment: I'm using Pandas to import the file and basically make all the changes. do you guys recommend that I just use other packages like adaptors or  cdv-importers? ( I like using pandas and since I already made the whole program before, I prefer to just implement it instead of doing the whole thing again with another package).

Comment: You should not be using pandas in your django application. Perform all of your pandas operations and save the output to another csv, then read that in using a third party package or use the csv module inside the get_or_create method of the model. You should really just save the output to a sqlite file instead of using csvs though as Django works natively with sqlite databases and they offer a safer data storage solution.

Comment: So can have a pytyon file where I make all my pandas operations and then save the new csv file. Then from views read that file? I'll play with the idea of saving it to a sqlite file and work from there. This is a better approach. Thanks, man.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sqlite is simple to work with and since Django is made to work with databases I'd highly recommend using it. You can simply use [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to make a new sqlite database and then just pass in the name of the database to DATABASES in your Django settings.py

Comment: Hey @PeterDannemann, Could you help me with using pandas 'to_sql'? I'm having a hard time saving that sql DB I created with pandas (in order to pass it to Django settings.) I think where I'm stuck is with SQLAlchemy and 'create engine' function. Unfortunately I can't share my code here. But I'll share the related lines: 'import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql('budgt',con=conn)'

Comment: `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`  
                                                                                                                  
`engine = create_engine('sqlite://')`                                                 
                                                                                                   
`df.to_sql('budgt', con=engine)`

Comment: Thanks, @PeterDannemann, I actually had solved it before I saw your answer. Now I'm have a problem with actually using that database!. I passed the database name to DATABASES dict in settings and I actually used a DB browser to check and the data is there yet I can't use it in Django. Sorry for all these questions. I don't mean to be annoying, I actually went through documents and videos and google but no luck. Sorry again.

Comment: You need to learn to figure out things on your own. These are all in Django's documentation. Your database file needs to be in the base directory of your project. Then you need to sync your models and migrations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/